# How can I calculate means every 24rows in R?

Tags: r

There is a sample data set which is including hourly wind speed and direction.

I want to know how calculate daily mean. But I have no idea.

please help me.

```
                 V1  V2    V3
1   2015-07-15 0:00 0.3 296.9
2   2015-07-15 1:00 0.4 215.2
3   2015-07-15 2:00 0.4 204.8
4   2015-07-15 3:00 0.7 110.8
5   2015-07-15 4:00 0.4 287.6
6   2015-07-15 5:00 0.2 203.4
7   2015-07-15 6:00 0.1 253.1
8   2015-07-15 7:00 0.4  46.0
9   2015-07-15 8:00 0.5 298.8
10  2015-07-15 9:00 0.8  62.8
11 2015-07-15 10:00 0.9 183.4
12 2015-07-15 11:00 1.6  62.3
13 2015-07-15 12:00 2.8  44.3
14 2015-07-15 13:00 3.0  97.6
15 2015-07-15 14:00 3.3  78.6
16 2015-07-15 15:00 4.9 125.6
17 2015-07-15 16:00 4.9 116.9
18 2015-07-15 17:00 3.6 121.0
19 2015-07-15 18:00 1.8 111.2
20 2015-07-15 19:00 1.8 335.8
21 2015-07-15 20:00 1.5 287.4
22 2015-07-15 21:00 2.1  51.7
23 2015-07-15 22:00 0.4 232.6
24 2015-07-15 23:00 0.8 265.5
25  2015-07-16 0:00 0.2 269.7
26  2015-07-16 1:00 1.0  20.5
27  2015-07-16 2:00 2.4  17.0
28  2015-07-16 3:00 1.0 310.8
29  2015-07-16 4:00 0.7  63.8
.
.
.
.
n sample
```

Comment: Please learn how to [format your question text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Extract the date from your datetime column (`V1`) and calculate a mean by date.

Comment: thanks for your help. I have a additional question. I got a daily calculating method but I need various time interval mean too for example 6hour mean etc.... How can I do this?